What is the equivalent concept to Agent in Spring AI?
I was working on learning some Spring AI and I noticed there wasn't a concept of agent. There is a concept of ChatClient and ChatModel which could be used similar to the idea IMHO but there is no real Agent class. It seems based on the definition of the Langchain Agent that it would be a ChatModel with defined advisors but I am unsure.
So my question is the equivalent of an Agent?

I think it just means code that is autonomous... think like you're an actor and you have a talent agent that makes phone calls, sets up auditions, collects/negotiates fees, etc...  They only need to get to know their client, and then can work for them on their own.  But basically it's a buzzword that's made up to sell frameworks.  It's sort of expanding on the term user-agent to mean something like a browser.  (which isn't quite autonomous, but does lots of things for us that we don't have to do manually)

In terms of programming think like "worker thread"... but not as clearly defined.
